# Problemas con la ruta delete con laravel para borrar un registro

Tags: laravel

El problema que tengo es que no me esta dando acceso ala ruta y si tengo el permiso al principio me decia que no encontraba el metodo de la ruta delete entonces investigue y hay que avisarle ala ruta con {{method_field('delete') entonces lo que hice se lo concatene pero ahora no tengo acceso ala ruta para que me lleve al contrador no se si es problema de la ruta o cual puede ser

```
<a class="btn btn-success"
         href=" {{url('empleado_editar/'.$users->id)}}">
         <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
     </a>

          <a class="btn btn-danger"
    href="{{method_field('delete').url('usuarios.eliminar/'.$users->id)}}">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </a>
```

estas son mis 2 rutas la primera me funciona bien ya la segunda no

```
Route::get('usuarios.consultar/{id}','UserController@show')->name('users.show')
        ->middleware('permission:users.show');

 Route::delete('usuarios.eliminar/{id}','UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy')
        ->middleware('permission:users.destroy');
```

estos son mis controladores el primero si me funciona el segundo no

```
public function show(User $id)
    {

        return view('usuarios.show',compact('id'));
    }


    public function destroy(User $id)
    {
        $id->delete();
        return back();
    }
    /**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacer una solicitud DELETE desde un navegador, por lo cual debes enviarlo como un parámetro de un formulario POST (idealmente):

```
<form action="{{url('usuarios.eliminar/'.$users->id)}}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

En caso que desees mantener el html como lo tienes, deberás hacer el envío del formulario con JavaScript.

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono tal y como lo dijiste